# can you stop a model from going out of bounds?

Tags: regression

Here is an example I thought of recently. Suppose in the year 2000, 1 dollar could get you 10 apples. In 2005, 1 dollar could get you 8 apples. In 2010, 1 dollar could get you 7 apples. In 2015, 1 dollar could get you 8 apples. In 2020, 1 dollar could get you 5 apples.

If we put a regression through this data, you will probably see that in the year 2050, 1 dollar will get you negative apples and obviously this is not possible. Is there a way to make some sort of asymptote which will make it so that even in the year 9999, 1 dollar will at the least get you 0 apples and not result in negative apples (ex: out of bounds?)

Comment: Sure, Poisson regression does and is specifically designed for modeling counts. Linear regression is one of the few models that doesn't bound the outcomes.

Comment: For things like prices, taking logarithms can often make sense.  If prices double [halve] and then double [halve] again over an equivalent time period then the pattern of the logarithms is linear.  If you then extrapolate forwards or backwards, the logarithms may or may not become negative but the associated prices (using antilogarithms) will always be positive.

Comment: Use a model specification that obeys any bounds on means (and other aspects of the conditional distribution -- minima, maxima, variances etc). I highly recommend looking into  generalized linear models as a first step. Transformation can sometimes work but it's much more likely to lead people very badly astray if they don't understand the tool properly, such not understanding the distinction between the marginal distribution of the response and the conditional distribution of the response, or not understanding the problems with ... ctd

Comment: ctd  ... trying to get back to a proper mean forecast after a log transformation; where the (t-distributed) pivotal quantity taken back to the original scale doesn't have any moments. There's a number of other issues with transformation -- it's *seemingly* straightforward, but it's an easy topic to teach badly; GLMs are more complex at first view but are much easier to teach well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily.

Remember that regression allows us to specify the conditional expectation of the data as a function of observed variables.  Your example in terms of apples ($y$) and time ($t$) might be

$$ E[y \mid t] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t $$

Indeed, if you fit a regression you will see that the predicted values are non-physical; you can't buy negative apples with non-negative money!
[image]

One way to get around this is to specify $E[y \mid x]$ to have some asymptote.  The easiest way is to fit a regression to $\log(y)$ instead of $y$. The regression function would be $E[\log(y) \mid x] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$.  Predicted on the scale of $y$,  that would look like

[image]

You can see that the function a) fits the data fairly well, and b) will approach 0 which is more realistic.